# How to change time of video created in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

By going into Properties --> Details --> Origin --> Media created, I can change only date of the "Media created" and not time. How can I change time also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [BulkFileChanger](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html): among other things, it also [allows you to change](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/change-media-created-acquired-date-multiple-mp4.html) date and time for "media created" property.

Comment: wow, it's better than Total Commander.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, Win11, videos generated by GoPro H7. I figured out this and hope it helps. https://superuser.com/a/1806020/656261

Answer (score 2):

Once again, the StackExchange upside down rules strike again. I cannot comment on something, but I can actual suggest what others should do. Fine. This is how StackExchange wants it, this is how they get it.

Despite what the answer says, it is - at a minimum - invalid for some people. For MOV files on a Windows 10 Home 21H2 system, this cannot be done using BulkFileChanger (both v1.7 and v1.72). I have personally tried the solution, and tried every other time field possible, and it has no effect. There are three time field options with check boxes (created, modified, accessed) and nine in the drop-down. The nine include three EXIF fields (generated, stored, modified), three media files fields (item, encoded, acquired), two document files fields (content created, last saved), and a Photo-Date Taken field. There is also a check box you can try to set time to GMT. NONE of these fields are changing the Media Created time mentioned in the answer. They work on other date/time fields, but not the one in the question. So, the answer is it cannot be done as stated.

If someone does not like this answer, try doing something helpful and put this information underneath the other answer.

Of course, god forbid, stackexchange rules might prevent that. How it is any person can provide misguided answers but only reputable people can provide less influential comments? This has been gobsmacking me for the ages I have known this site to exist. As for the rule "be polite and have fun", it will never be a happy time trying to be helpful on this site when this site prohibits users from *only* being helpful by pointing out problems with answers while it has no problem authorizing you to post answers that are completely wrong. (It doesn't matter if people might take action in response to incorrect answers. That it is authorized for no-rep people but simple comments are prohibited is a mega-example of the long-term persistence of group-think no matter how much logic goes against it.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).