# How to change mp4 windows file creation date to create date from QuickTime

Tags: windows-10, mp4, exiftool

I have seen many similar questions to this, but can't sus out this exact problem:
I take a lot of GoPro videos during my motorcycle adventures.  While on the road I will upload video files to a cloud storage solution (GoPro Plus Media Library in one case) so that I can clear my SD chips.  When I get home I download the files so I can edit.  My editing tool sees the correct date that the video we taken (2018-04-21) but Windows Explorer shows and sorts as the File's created/modified date (2022-05-17). I keep my files organized by the date they were shot and it's much easier if the original "shot" date is the what Windows sees to sort by. ExifTool (GUI) shows that it can see the QuickTime CreateDate, but I can't figure out the steps to change the Windows Create & Modified date to the QT CreatDate.  Help?  Thanks!

Comment: See https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=5007.0 for info on web from ExifTool site.

Comment: You can use PowerShell or [BulkFileChanger](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-accessed-modified-created-file-date-timestamp-windows/#bulkfilechanger) tool to modify the date created/modified stamp en masse.

Answer (score 2):

@StarGeek's answer inspired me.

My problem is that I bought a second-hand gopro and didn't update the system time. It created so much headache and I managed to adjust the **create date** successfully with `exiftool`.

**create date** decides how you photos and videos are sorted in Windows, also how they are sorted when you upload to iCloud and later synced into your iPhone.

[image]

Without using 3rd party tools, you can only edit date but not time.

---

`irfanView` can modify the create date and time, but only for photos.

See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-edit-the-time-in-the-date-taken-field-under/7589131e-3ed0-4bb6-991d-934d3e644d10

---

`exiftool` can modify the create date and time for videos. But it takes some effort to get it.

HowTo:

1. https://exiftool.org/ , download `Windows Executable: exiftool-12.65.zip (6.9 MB)`
2. extract, you get a `exiftool(-k).exe`. You can click and drag a video onto this exe, then it will open the file and display the video's meta infos.
3. To modify create date, use/ajust this command in Windows cmd.

```
"exiftool(-k).exe"  -overwrite_original -CreateDate="2023:08:19 02:20:01" GX010020.MP4
```

---

At last, this could help https://community.gopro.com/s/article/GoPro-Camera-File-Naming-Convention?language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) but video time stamps can be tricky.  They are supposed to be set to UTC and many programs do not correctly read the embedded time stamp, reading it instead as local time. Additionaly, many cameras do not set it correctly as UTC, again, using local time. The first thing you want to do is make sure the time stamp in the video is correct.

First, you want to Right-Click->Properties->Details tab.  From there, you want to look at the "Media Created" entry
[image: Window Details Tab]

Windows will correctly read the video timestamp as UTC and adjust it accordingly. If Window is displaying the correct time, adjusted to your time zone if it is different from where the video was shot, then the time in the file is correctly set to UTC.  This information is needed so the correct exiftool command will be used.

If the time is set to UTC, then the command you want to run would be

```
exiftool -api QuickTimeUTC "-FileModifyDate<CreateDate" "-FileCreateDate<CreateDate" /path/to/files/
```

If the embedded time is instead local, then you would run

```
exiftool "-FileModifyDate<CreateDate" "-FileCreateDate<CreateDate" /path/to/files/
```

The [`-api QuickTimeUTC` option](https://exiftool.org/ExifTool.html#QuickTimeUTC) tells exiftool that the embedded time stamp is correctly set to UTC and to adjust it accordingly when it is used.

These commands create backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.